# for each with 2 observable collections

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a teams and rank scoring collection to track, say a relay race.

So as a user enter teams into collection, each team will be awarded points based on ranking.

https://jsfiddle.net/2ae3dv8d/

```
<strong>Teams:</strong>
<!-- ko foreach: teams -->
<div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->


function Team(name)
{
  var self = this;
  self.name = name'
}

function RankScoring(label, points){
  var self = this;
  self.label = label;
  self.points = points;
}

function AppViewModel()
{
  var self = this;
  self.teams = ko.observableArray([
    new Team('red'),
    new Team('blue')
  ]);
  self.rankscoring = ko.observableArray([
    new RankScoring('1st', ''),
    new RankScoring('2nd', ''),
    new RankScoring('3rd', ''),
  ]);
}
```

In this particular example, let's say the game had 2 teams. So, I'm only going to need to use 2 items from RankScoring collection based on the number of teams involved. **How do I data-bind RankScoring collection so user can enter points for rankings?** And I welcome suggestions for easier way to accomplish the idea.

```
**Teams:**
Red
Blue

**Scoring**
1st place - 10
2nd place - 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a computed to show textboxes for available ranks:

```
self.availablerankscoring = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.rankscoring().slice(0,self.teams().length);
});
```

Add another foreach for available ranks:

```knockout
<!-- ko foreach: availablerankscoring -->
<div>
    <label data-bind="text: label"></label><input type="text" data-bind="value: points" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tschettler/2ae3dv8d/3/)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated based on this to allow user input for the same number of ranks as there are teams.

Comment: You got it! Thank you : )